# Multi selection picker view cant have more options in one than others

Tags: swift, swift2, uipickerview

## Aim:

- To setup a selector to pick an age, a player number and innings
- Values for ages should be 8,9,10
- Values for numbers should be 0-99 for
- Values for innings should be 1-6

## Problem:

Only 3 options show up in each when i test it if there are more in the array they don't show up and if there are less it crashes.

## Questions:

- How to display the correct number of options for each item ?
- How to make the 0-99 picker go 0,1,2... without having to list each individual number like 0...99(I tried this and it doesn't work) ?

## Code:

```
import UIKit

class PitcherPickerViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    
     var pickerData: [[String]] = [[String]]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        // Connect data:
        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self
        
        // Input data into the Array:
        pickerData = [["8", "9", "10"],
            ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99"],
            ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    
    // The number of columns of data
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    // The number of rows of data
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }
    
    // The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[component][row]
    }
    
    // Catpure the picker view selection
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
        // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pickerData` is an array of arrays

Try the following:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData[component].count
}
```

If you don't want continuous numbers change the `pickerData` accordingly because that is what is being used in the `titleForRow` delegate method.

Comment: +1 thanks man i saw when you posted it like 15 or so days ago but i guess my comment never when through you are literally a life saver i cant believe a small thing can seriously change everything thanks again